# python regex match not working

Tags: python, regex

It might be a silly question but i can not get it working.

```
import re
def name_validator(value):
    reg = re.compile(r'^\D*&')
    if not reg.match(value):
        raise ValueError
```

I want to match any string that do not contains digits. But it always raise ValueError.

```
>>> import re
def name_validator(value):
    reg = re.compile(r'^\D*&')
    if not reg.match(value):
        raise ValueError
>>> name_validator('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 5, in name_validator
ValueError
```

Comment: It's worth using something like https://regex101.com/#python to help you catch these mistakes early.

Comment: yeah. typo.. thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to match any string that does not contains digits.

The `\D` matches a non-digit symbol. A `^\D*$` matches an empty string and any string without digits inside.

You need to use

```
reg = re.compile(r'\D*$') # Note  DOLLAR symbol at the end
if not reg.match(value):
```

Or

```
reg = re.compile(r'^\D*$') # Note the CARET symbol at the start and the DOLLAR symbol at the end
if not reg.search(value):
```